# How to count count customers that have only 1 product / all products

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this:

| id | name | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ben | x |
| 2 | Ann | y |
| 3 | Kate | y |
| 4 | John | x |
| 4 | John | y |

I wonder:

1. How to count customers who have only x product?
2. How to count customers who have both products?

Comment: Please don't tag PL/SQL or desktop tools when the question is about SQL. PL/SQL isn't a query language, and the "SQL Developer" and "PL/SQL Developer" tags aren't about developers who work with SQL and PL/SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use these two queries to get job done

1. How to count customers who have only x product?

```sql
select t.ID, t.NAME
from t
group by t.ID, t.NAME
having count(distinct t.PRODUCT) = 1 
  and max(t.PRODUCT) = 'x'
;
```

2. How to count customers who have both products?
   You could use this analytic solution for that

```sql
select distinct ID, NAME
from (
select t.ID, t.NAME, t.PRODUCT, count(distinct t.PRODUCT)over(partition by t.ID ) cnt
from t
where t.PRODUCT in ('x', 'y')
)
where cnt > 1
```

or you could also use this aggregate solution

```sql
select t.ID, t.NAME
from t
where t.PRODUCT in ('x', 'y')
group by t.ID, t.NAME
having listagg(t.PRODUCT, ',')within group (order by t.PRODUCT) like '%x,y%'
;
```

Here I used a comma separator for the listagg aggregate function because I assumed none of your product names contain a comma ",". Otherwise you need to choose properly your owner separator for listagg function.

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=71bd598ca588f28cb7dc0915bcf17a6d)

Answer (score 0):

For only x product:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE PRODUCT='x'
```

For both products:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(NAME)) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

For customer that has only x product:

```
SELECT PRODUCT, COUNT(NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE PRODUCT='x' GROUP BY PRODUCT
```

Comment: But John has both x and y products. I want to count customer who has only x product, for example: Ben.

Comment: Oh sorry, i misunderstood the problem. Then, try this: SELECT PRODUCT, COUNT(NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE PRODUCT='x' GROUP BY PRODUCT

Comment: @MəhəmmədOcaqzadə: In the future, please edit your answer to include corrections or updates, instead of simply replying in the comments. I've edited your proposal into your answer on your behalf. While I was at it, I also improved the formatting so it's more readable.